# Create R data frame row-wise

Tags: r, dataframe

How to create a data frame in R providing the data row-wise? I am looking for a one statement solution.

This is the one statement solution for column-wise:

```
mydf = data.frame(
    fruit = c("apple", "orange", "banana"),
    pieces = c(3, 2, 5)
)
```

I find the row-wise approach more logical (imagine that we have hundreds of entries), therefore I am looking for such a solution.

I made some investigations. The simplest solution I found is this:

```
mymatrix <- rbind(
    c("apple", 3), 
    c("orange", 2), 
    c("banana", 5)
)
colnames(mymatrix) <- c("fruit", "pieces")
mydf = as.data.frame(mymatrix)
mydf = transform(mydf, pieces=as.numeric(pieces))
```

But as an extra variable and multiple step transformation is needed, I still find it too complicated. Is there a one statement solution to that, similar to the column-wise approach?

Comment: `tribble()`?  `tibble() %>% add_row(fruit="Orange", pieces=3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tribble` from `tibble` package for Row-wise tibble creation

```
library(tibble)

mydf <- tribble(
~fruit, ~pieces, 
"apple", 3, 
"orange", 2,
"banana", 5
)
```